# Breaking a while loop defined in a method, calling the break condition from another method

Tags: python, class, while-loop

I defined a class with two methods: *StartRecording* and *StopRecording*. The former implements a while loop for data recording in real-time, the latter breaks the recording.
The while loop works until the elapsed time exceed a constant value. Let's say 3000ms.
Here is the Python code.

```
class MyClass():
    def StartRecording(self):
        ...
        while elapsedTime < 3000:
        #do something
    
    def StopRecording(self):
        ...
        #do something
```

I would like to transform the break condition of the while loop. So I decided to use a boolean variable declared in the **init** and to modify its value in the *StopRecording* function.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.m_lock = Lock()
        self.isRecording = None

    def StartRecording(self):
        ...
        self.isRecording = True
        while self.isRecording:
           #do something
    
    def StopRecording(self):
        ...
        self.isRecording = False
        #do something
```

The class is defined in a module which is called from another script

```
import MyClassFile as mcf
import time

device = mcf.MyClass()
device.StartRecording()
time.sleep(3)
device.StopRecording()
```

Unfortunately, the recording doesn't stop! How can I modify it properly?

Comment: Can you show an example where the latter doesn't work?

Comment: Where do you call `self.stopRecording()`?

Comment: Are you calling `StopRecording` from a different thread, perhaps?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo That should be OK.

Comment: Please post a [mre]

Comment: You need to instanciate the class and then call the method on the instance

Comment: The problem is that you have a single thread. So you start recording, but the loop runs forever because you do not have another thread that can change the value of `isRecording` to False while the loop in `startRecording` is executing.

Comment: How can I define this second thread? Could you provide a solution?

Answer (score -1):

Following your example:

```
import MyClass as mc
import time

mc.StartRecording()
time.sleep(3)
mc.StopRecording()
```

You should create an instance of the class and then use that to start and stop the recording:

```
import MyClass as mc
import time

recorder_instance = mc()
recorder_instance.StartRecording()
time.sleep(3)
recorder_instance.StopRecording()
```